# Matrix Multiplication(Python3.x)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I would like to two integers which are receiving the user as a matrix;
For example:

```
m=int(input(enter the row number")
n=int(input("enter the column number:
A=input("enter your matrix: ") 
print (A) #with column and row
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Where exactly are you doing any matrix multiplication here? Also, I would use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) for this.

Comment: Sorry actually multiplication will be next step but firstly i have to print matrix a and i think my teacher wont be pleased with numpy

Comment: What's the question then? Are you looking to find a way to create a matrix from a list of input characters?

Comment: Have you learned about loops?

Comment: Yes i have already learned loops but in loops my list exactly seems like A=[[1.2],[3,4]] that if it has 2 column and two row but i dont wanna this.Is there any solution to print line by line?